# How to setup domain to use own dns server exclusively

Tags: dns, hosting

For example, when I buy a domain from GoDaddy and I setup up my own DNS server, the first thing is to change the NS record on GoDaddy panel. But the NS record can only be in domain format.

How can I set my domain to use my own DNS server without any others?

Comment: "But the NS record can only be in domain format." — Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: _«own dns server exclusively»_ note that this is confusing, because DNS works with caches and that means many other DNS servers will have copies... Although you could reduce the caching timing to a few seconds, it is not guaranteed that re-querying will not give you an answer from a cache DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

You create an A record for your server ns.mydomain.com -> xx.xx.xx.xx
then you point the NS record to ns.mydomain.com

Comment: Thanks,I have found there is a HOSTNAME records setting,I can setup a hostname as ns1 and ns2,then use ns1.domain.com as my dns server.